# Undefined mixing error in codekit

Tags: css, sass, mixins, codekit

I can't figure out why I can't get mixins to work. Can you look at the info below and see if something's wrong. These are my sass pages and they include the relevant code.

```
**Style.sass**
@import "components/typography"
@import "components/tables"

**_typography.sass**
@mixin bold-caps
    font-weight: 700
    text-transform: capitalize

**_tables.sass**
p
    @include bold-caps
```

Comment: Can you post the error that your SASS precompiler is logging?

Comment: Error: Undefined mixin 'bold-caps'.
        on line 8 of /Users/krisjones/Desktop/style/components/_tables.sass, in `bold-caps'from line 8 of /Users/krisjones/Desktop/style/components/_tables.sass
        from line 8 of /Users/krisjones/Desktop/style/style2.sass
  Use --trace for backtrace.

Comment: Try the code in my post below... I just added "()" to the mixin declaration and the mixin call... I am pretty sure that is what is throwing the error

Comment: Still not getting it. Could it be that I'm using sass instead of scss?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Style.sass
@import "components/typography";
@import "components/tables";

//_typography.sass
@mixin bold-caps() {
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

//_tables.sass
p {
    @include bold-caps();
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.